# installing python onto my Bluehost server via ssh/terminal

Tags: python, web, ssh, installation

Installing python 2.7 onto my bluehost account via SSH. I'm using their installing [document](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/python-install). I'm at the part where I have to edit my bashrc file. I'm confuse as to what to do...

They say to add `export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH` to my bashrc script which is fine but I'm not sure if I'm replacing what I already have in there which is - `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`.

Do I replace what I have or add `export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH` above `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the line to your .bashrc. It won't matter if it comes before or after the other line. Each of the commands contains instructions about how to add its path to the larger path environment variable. If you are interested in how that works, you can read more here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/209859

Don't mind that the person answering in the link says to add path variables to .profile. Since Bluehost says to add it to .bashrc, you should be fine if you follow their instructions and put it in .bashrc.

As a side note, the Bluehost tutorial tells you to use vim to edit your file. If you are not already good at using vim, your life will be easier if you use nano instead.

Comment: Should I use the word “export”?

Comment: Yes.  You should add the line exactly as the tutorial says to add it.  `export` is the keyword for declaring an environment variable, so leaving it off would be bad.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. :)